# Hive create table from file with partition

Tags: hadoop, hive, bigdata, hiveql

I encountered a strange HIVE behavior which i can not completely understand. 
I really hope someone could shad some light on that matter.

I am using the following script to create and add data to a table:

```
DROP TABLE myTbl;
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE myTbl (
    Col1 string,
    Col2 string,  
    Col3 string,
    Col4  string,
)
PARTITIONED BY (partition STRING)
LOCATION '${hiveconf:Valid_location_on_aws_s3_with_the_proper_file_to_create_table}';
```

Hive runs the script returns OK but (Here is the problem) the table is empty.
run:
`select * from myTbl;` returns nothing

The solution for this problem was rather simple after the script i run the following command/script:

`MSCK REPAIR TABLE myTbl`

now when executing select on that table i can see all the data that was in the file.

What i can not understand is why I need to use the repair in order to see the data in the table.

P.S. using the LOAD INTO TABLE works perfectly without any need to repair.

Comment: Please don't use an ALL-CAPS title.

Answer (score 1):

It might have to do with the case that DROP TABLE removes metadata for all table's partitions. However CREATE TABLE doesn't recreate this info in metastore. So, after issuing CREATE TABLE Hive doesn't know yet that there are partitions and there is data in them. MSCK REPAIR TABLE recreates this information in metastore (or you could do it manually with ALTER TABLE tbl ADD PARTITION).

Comment: Thank you for your time! 
As far as i know drop external table does not drop metadata (please correct me if I'm wrong). Living that aside you are saying that even though I am  creating a table while using the partitioned by as written up it is not written to metadata?

Comment: DROP TABLE for external tables drops metadata. It doesn't drop data. Regarding your second question, yes, thats the case. I don't know how Hive treats data stored on AWS S3, but with regular data on HDFS each partition is a directory. If you create that directory manually and add data to it with, e.g. with hdfs -put, Hive will never know you've created it and there is data in there until you explicitly create a partition with ADD PARTITION or run MSCK REPAIR.